# Выбрать записи при условие что она последняя

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

имеется такой результат одного из select

нужно выбрать id(указал красным)

уловия такие: выбрать все записи у которых node_id = 3 и она последняя для task_id. (последним считается с наибольшим по полю id)

например для task_id=5 или 1 node_id=3 не последняя.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nörbörnën подсказал

```
select * from (
  select 
    id, 
    task_id,
    max(id) over (partition by task_id) as max_id,
    node_id
  from answer
) as table
where id = max_id and node_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Отсортировать по полю `task_id` и выбрать одну запись:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE node_id = 3 ORDER BY task_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: сортировка нужна по id это даст что запись последняя. 

а лимит выберет только одну, а у меня несколько подходящих.

Comment: так добавьте в выборку row_number over task_id

Comment: разверните словосочетание "она последняя". Что подразумевается под "она"?